# No output when using `fprintf' after `fwprintf'

Tags: c, linux, printf, stdio, wchar-t

This just happened to me while testing a part of a bigger program that I isolated. The original function would remove non ascii characters from a string in a special manner that I needed, the thing is this program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    fwprintf(stdout, L"-- Example\n");
    fprintf(stdout, "-- Example\n");

    return 0;
}
```

would not print the second `-- Example` on my linux (Fedora 22) system. Although using `fwprintf()` again or `fprintf(stderr, "-- Example\n");` would work.

- Is this the expected behavior? And why?

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: @trojanfoe Updated the tags.

Comment: does work with MSVC.

Comment: I think this issue might be related to the *wide orientation* of the file stream.  If `fwide()` is not used then the orientation of the first file function is used.  Once the stream is *wide* then you need to use *wide* functions.  You could confirm this by reversing your use of `fprintf()` and `fwprintf()`.

Comment: @trojanfoe I just tried `fwide(stdout, -1)` right before `fprintf(stdout, "-- Example\n");` and still doesn't work. Although your point does make sense, if `fwprintf()` does call `fwide()` probably `fprintf()` does it too.

Comment: You cannot change it once it's been set.  You need to be consistent with your use of (non-)wide functions on (non-)wide streams.

Comment: @trojanfoe I Just read that in the manual page for `fwide()`. It is definitely this problem. You can answer that if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this issue might be related to the *wide orientation* of the file stream. If `fwide()` is not used then the orientation of the first file function is used to determine the orientation (you can also set the orientation when opening file, but that doesn't apply here).

Once the stream is wide then you need to use wide functions; and when non-wide you need to use non-wide functions.

Once the orientation is set, it cannot be changed.

Comment: I'm reading your answer. I've tried to revert the wide direction and, as you say, it's not permitted to change it. I don't understand why this behaviour was imposed. Do you know the reason of this behaviour?